# Get current process identity and authentication information

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have a Windows Service running in a server with a specific identity, in a domain controlled by Active Directory.

I need to send this service identity to another service in the same network via TCP, using our own protocol and some kind of token to authenticate the caller in the destination server, similarly how Windows Authentication works with WCF or Windows Forms applications.

There is some way to do that (using .NET 4.5 and C#) without that I have to implement my own token service, using the AD/Windows infrastructure?

Comment: I would start here [Identity Management in Active Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/security/aa570351.aspx). Don't implement your own, find the one that suits your needs. It's very difficult to write this correctly from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I had a look on WIF / ADFS but I was thinking in something more straightforward, like generate a Kerberos ticket and send it to the service to validation, but I could not find how to do that in C# (and I'm not sure if its possible)...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using SSPI, like **bmm60** suggested. With SSPI, is possible to authenticate using Kerberos and NTLM.

There's a a C++ managed assembly to the SSPI calls in this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973911.aspx

The same article has a good explanation how the authentication process works.

I've found a C# wrapper too (but a little more difficult to use), in here:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32.initializesecuritycontext

Basically, the wrapper uses **InitializeSecurityContext** and **AcceptSecurityContext** Windows functions to provides the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest if you could leverage the built-in authentication of IIS or WCF.  If you really need a TCP socket, I think you have to implement the authentication yourself.  It's not conceptually difficult if you understand how Kerberos works, but it will take a while to work out the details of all the functions to call.  MSDN has a decent overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In addition, I'm not aware of any C# wrappers for these, so you would probably need to p-invoke them all; consider writing that part in managed C++.